# How to make unpitched percussion and a pitched instrument share a staff in LilyPond?

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving

For parts where the percussionist switches from vibraphone to maracas, for example, is there a way to combine the two on the same staff?  IIRC, LilyPond treats normal staves and percussion staffs completely separately.

Comment: Did you check the Lilypond Documentation online (http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-percussion)? It is totally possible to combine different percussion instruments in one staff. If the documentation does not contain your specific problem, please explain a bit more detailed what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was specifically referring to pitches and unpitched instruments sharing a staff. `\drummode` is completely useless for the vibraphone sections of the part: the vibes need normal note entry.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But I fear the only thing you can try is just using a pitched staff for the maracas as well. If you need midi output you can add an invisible additional drum staff that is just used for midi output.

Comment: Say the maracas are a B-flat and override the staff to have one line and give an x notehead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear the only thing you can try is to just use a pitched staff for the maracas. You can adjust the visibility of accidentals and the line count of the system with overrides.

I am not fully sure, how your score will look in the end, but perhaps you could start like this:

```
\version "2.18.2"

startMaracas = {
  \stopStaff
  \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
  \override Staff.Accidental.stencil = ##f
  \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
  \startStaff
  \once \override Staff.BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-2 . 2)
}

endMaracas = {
  \stopStaff
  \revert Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count
  \revert Staff.Accidental.stencil
  \revert NoteHead.style
  \startStaff
}

\score {
  <<
  \new Staff {
    c'4^\markup{ "Vibraphone" } d' e' f' 
    c'4 d' e' f' 
    \startMaracas 
    bes'4^\markup{ "Maracas" } bes' bes' bes'
    bes'4 bes' bes' bes'
    \endMaracas 
    c'4^\markup{ "Vibraphone" } d' e' f' 
    c'4 d' e' f' 
  } 
  >>
}
```

Rendering as:

[image]

---

You can add the following function to your code if you want to use `\changeInstrument "maracas"` or `\changeInstrument "somethingelse"` instead of the defined macros:

```
changeInstrument = #(define-music-function (parser location instrument) (string?)
  (if (equal? instrument "maracas") 
    #{ \startMaracas #}
    #{ \endMaracas #} ) 
  )
```

Comment: Could `\startMaracas` and `\endMaracas` be refactored to `\instrumentSwitch "vibes"` and `\instrumentSwitch "maracas"` (with the accompanying instrument switch definitions more or less identical to your start & end maracas definitions)?

Comment: You could add a short scheme function to redefine your code. See my edit.

Comment: I've been studying the score for a concert band piece lately (*Shadow Rituals* by Michael Markowski), and in that piece, I've seen unpitched percussion instruments share *five-line* staves with pitched percussion instruments.