# LilyPond: Is it possible to create an instrument switch that goes from a Staff to a DrumStaff and back?

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving

I'm typesetting a piece where a singer alternates between singing and playing maracas while never doing both at the same time.

I would like to use a single stave and make an instrument switch using \addInstrumentDefinition and \instrumentSwitch, but the documentation on it isn't terribly expansive. For instance, there is only this example:

```
\addInstrumentDefinition #"contrabassoon"
  #`((instrumentTransposition . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 0 0))
     (shortInstrumentName . "Cbsn.")
     (clefGlyph . "clefs.F")
     (middleCPosition . 6)
     (clefPosition . 2)
     (instrumentCueName . ,(make-bold-markup "cbsn."))
     (midiInstrument . "bassoon"))
```

Which leaves the question open on the complete list of parameters (i.e. "context properties and values") the syntax etc. --In my case: Is there a way to change to DrumStaff? How do I set the drumStyleTable? etc.

If it is impossible to go back and forth between Staff and DrumStaff with this method, is there another method that allows this? If not, I might follow the solution suggested in [How to make unpitched percussion and a pitched instrument share a staff in LilyPond?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/90727/how-to-make-unpitched-percussion-and-a-pitched-instrument-share-a-staff-in-lilyp)

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation has been mostly removed because it just is easier to create some music with overrides in it.

That approach obviously would have no problems including staff changes, while `addInstrumentDefinition` by principle cannot include anything you cannot achieve via setting context properties.